# C++ call method of not yet constructed object

Tags: c++

The last time I got downvoted so I tried to make my question more clear.
Here is the code:

my_header.h

```
class A;

class B {
public:
  B(A* a);

  int GetValue() { return value_; }

private:
  int value_;
};

class A {
public:
  A() {
   b = new B(this);
  }

  void PrintValue() {
    std::cout <<  "GetValue() called from A::PrintValue() = " << b->GetValue() << "\n";
  }

private:
  B* b;
};

B::B(A* a) : value_(100) {
  std::cout << "GetValue() called from B::B(A* a) = " << GetValue() << "\n";
  a->PrintValue();
}
```

and main.cc

```
    #include "my_header.h"

    int main() {
      A a;
      return 0;
    }
```

And the output was:

```
GetValue() called from B::B(A* a) = 100
GetValue() called from A::PrintValue() = 1
```

I know it is a very bad idea to call methods of object that has not yet been constructed properly. But I dont understand why `GetValue()` called from `PrintValue()` returns 1 even though `value_` has been already initialized to 100, as we see from the string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A::b` is not set to the address of the new `B` object until after `B`'s constructor finishes.

When `B`'s constructor calls `a->PrintValue()`, the latter invokes `b->GetValue()` while `b` has not been initialized. So you get undefined behaviour by accessing `b`.

Comment: Thanks! Ohhh stupid mistske, I should definitly learn more c++.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. As you say, the `A` object has not been constructed, so calling `PrintValue` with a pointer to where the `A` object will later be produces nonsense. Don't try to reason about it. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You begged and begged for *undefined behavior* and that's what the compiler gave you.  <strike>A is not fully constructed.</strike>  In particular, `b` has not been assigned and wasn't initialized to anything in particular.  Your program might do anything.